# Comparing certain column names in two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, comparison, columnsorting

I am looking for a way to compare two different data frame column names (only certain ranges of columns) and keeping only the names that have the same shared similarity of column names between the two data frames. (I only want to compare each data frame from a certain point forward only though.

I would have a significantly larger number of columns, so i want to see what would work best in larger data sets.

Say i have DF1

| ID | Location | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | Park | 4 | 3 | 3 |
| Second | House | 2 | 5 | 2 |
| Second | Barn | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| Third | Lake | 1 | 8 | 8 |
| Third | Airport | 7 | 5 | 4 |
| Fourth | Car | 4 | 5 | 1 |

And DF2

| Name | Identifier | City | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jeff | ISE2 | Seattle | 1 | 6 |
| George | GSY7 | Houston | 2 | 2 |
| Carl | BHU1 | Miami | 3 | 7 |
| Mike | POI0 | Los Angeles | 8 | 8 |
| Linel | ANN1 | DC | 5 | 4 |
| Pork | CNU4 | Portland | 5 | 1 |

In DF1, we will keep ID and Location column regardless, and for DF2, we keep Name, Identifier, and City regardless. My goal is to compare the other numerical columns to see if there is a match in the name. So in this case, the match is "Value2" and "Value3."

So the processed data frames would be:

New DF1

| ID | Location | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | Park | 4 | 3 |
| Second | House | 2 | 5 |
| Second | Barn | 4 | 5 |
| Third | Lake | 1 | 8 |
| Third | Airport | 7 | 5 |
| Fourth | Car | 4 | 5 |

And new DF2

| Name | Identifier | City | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jeff | ISE2 | Seattle | 1 | 6 |
| George | GSY7 | Houston | 2 | 2 |
| Carl | BHU1 | Miami | 3 | 7 |
| Mike | POI0 | Los Angeles | 8 | 8 |
| Linel | ANN1 | DC | 5 | 4 |
| Pork | CNU4 | Portland | 5 | 1 |

Is one way comparing the column names of each DF and compare it to the other? I would appreciate any help on this. Thank you!

```
ID <- c("First", "Second", "Second", "Third", "Third", "Fourth")
Location <- c("Park","House","Barn","Lake","Airport","Car")
Value2 <- c(4,2,4,1,7,4)
Value3 <- c(3,5,5,8,5,5)
Value4 <- c(3,2,6,8,4,1)
DF1 <- data.frame(ID, Location, Value2, Value3, Value4)
```

```
Name <- c("Jeff", "George", "Carl", "Mike", "Linel", "Pork")
Identifier <- c("ISE2","GSY2","BHU1","POI0","ANN1","CNU4")
City <- c("Seattle","Houston","Miami","Los Angeles","DC","Portland")
Value2 <- c(1,2,3,8,5,5)
Value3 <- c(6,2,7,8,4,1)
DF2 <- data.frame(Name, Identifier, City, Value2, Value3)
```

Comment: I think you mean `DF2 <- data.frame(Name, Identifier, City, Value2, Value3)`

Comment: `intersect(names(DF1), names(DF2))` yields `c("Value2", "Value3")`, is that what you need?

Comment: ^ +1: Sample data at the bottom of your post is confusing and doesn't match your problem description (`DF1` and `DF2` have the same column names). Also your original sample data has other columns that are not shared between `DF1` and `DF2` but that you seem to want to retain (`ID`, `Location`, `City`, etc.).

Comment: Whoops! Fixed the DF2 name portion. I want to intersect the names, but is there a way to keep a customized number of columns from being "intersected" among?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R option

```r
# Common column-name pattern across `data.frame`
pattern <- "Value"
common_nms <- intersect(
    names(DF1)[grep(pattern, names(DF1))], 
    names(DF2)[grep(pattern, names(DF2))])

# Unique and and "pattern-shared" columns in `DF1`
DF1[c(names(DF1)[-grep(pattern, names(DF1))], common_nms)]
#      ID Location Value2 Value3
#1  First     Park      4      3
#2 Second    House      2      5
#3 Second     Barn      4      5
#4  Third     Lake      1      8
#5  Third  Airport      7      5
#6 Fourth      Car      4      5

# Unique and and "pattern-shared" columns in `DF2`
DF2[c(names(DF2)[-grep(pattern, names(DF2))], common_nms)]
#    Name Identifier        City Value2 Value3
#1   Jeff       ISE2     Seattle      1      6
#2 George       GSY2     Houston      2      2
#3   Carl       BHU1       Miami      3      7
#4   Mike       POI0 Los Angeles      8      8
#5  Linel       ANN1          DC      5      4
#6   Pork       CNU4    Portland      5      1
```

The idea is to use a `pattern` to filter column names and then determine common names through `intersect`. Final column names are then given by column names that don't match the `pattern` (the "unique" names) and the common column names from the intersect.

Comment: Thank you! If the Value2, 3, 4 were all different names, what alternative would I be able to do to adjust the code?

Comment: In that case you'd need to think about a rule/logic that allows you to treat those columns separately from those columns that you consider "unique" (per `data.frame`). Regular expressions might be a way; or not. The devil is in the detail here.